"as" and the subject
I often encounter sentences constructed like this:

As a teenager, my family was poor.

My gut tells me that if you define a subject like that with "as" (or "being"), the following part of sentence should also base on the same subject, so rather:

As a teenager, I was poor.

That would also be a common mistake in my mother language.
I cannot find a confirmation though, I probably don't know how to form a proper phrase when searching for it.

I don't think it's invariable. You could get away with the as-clause referring to the object: "As a stand, I used a cardboard box." Certainly "As a teenager, my father was poor" would naturally be thought to refer to "my father" not me. But that's not a matter of grammar.

"As a teenager" is not the subject and it's not a clause; it's a preposition phrase functioning as a supplement with a meaning similar to "when I was a teenager". There is generally no absolute requirement for the supplement to have a subject that matches the one in the main clause, indeed it need not have a subject at all, as is the case in your example. In examples like yours, we determine the subject by inference.

There are several terms for this type of problematic usage. They often start with the word "dangling" or "misplaced". Here is the Wikipedia article on "dangling modifiers": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier

Gut is singular; guts is plural.

If anyone was wondering what Xanne comment refers to: You need guts to do something courageous but your gut feeling helps you make the right decision.

@Mari-LouA I guess she meant A1 mistake which I made initially, writing "guts tell me" ;) is it fine now or I should put "feeling" too for it to be correct?

This question is a duplicate of "As a {noun}" followed by mismatching subject

You are quite correct. See this question from ELL, particularly the second answer. It's a common error in English.

The question you use as a reference has nothing to do with whether the subject should refer to the entity mentioned in the prepositional phrase or not; instead, it is a question about the ambiguity that arises from several possible interpretations of "as": "quality" and "time" (in the quality of a child, in childhood).

@LPH - True, but the second answer does. It was the only reference I could find, though the Wikipedia article on dangling modifiers explains it better. I've always found it jarring, though other commenters seem to consider it acceptable.

I do not find it acceptable in the OP's sentence, because neither a subject nor an object can be said to be described by the noun phrase; it seems that at least one of those is needed.

dangling modifiers article explains it indeed, but now I'm not sure which answer to accept, because I like yours the most and yet it has the least upvotes :D and I don't really see a source like a dictionary in any of them which would back up people's opinions

"second answer" is ambiguous. The order of answers is not consistent, since there's a menu for sorting the answers, and unless you sort by creation time, it can change over time.

The target of the property ascribed by the as-phrase does not have to be the subject of the clause. Any rule to the contrary is style advice and not a serious take on the grammar of the construction. Context determines the salient interpretation.

As a teenager, no one liked me. [object]
As a teenager, people said I shouldn't work so hard. [subject of subordinate clause]

It can even work when there is no pronoun or noun phrase as a target.

As a teenager, everything seemed possible. [understood to me]


The one benefit of the doubt I'd give OP is that when there's multiple interpretations, the subject tends to win out over all others, e.g. "As a teenager, Adam used to tell jokes about Bernard to Cindy" refers to Adam being a teenager, while Bernard and Cindy's ages are unspecified.

All of your examples mention the teenager, either explicitly or implicitly ("[understood to me]").  The example sentence doesn't, and I would agree with the OP that's it improperly constructed.  It's implying that the family was once a teenager.  (I suppose you could argue that "my" is implicitly referring to the teenager, but the sentence still feels awkward to me.)

@GentlePurpleRain There's no reason why the target can't be a genitive pronoun. Examples abound: "As your teacher, my concern is to help you improve your writing, to be your ally."  Dislocation has a similar effect: "These students I teach, their abilities are quite above normal."

I admit that in English the matter you are asking about sits at least close to the boundary between descriptivism and prescriptivism, and that in colloquial conversation you’ll encounter things like your As a teenager, my family was poor quite commonly. But in careful writing anyway, your intuition is on the money.
Indeed, consider

As a child, she used to give me ice cream.

Who was the child, she or I?
To be fair, that example is fairly contrived, and in nearly all cases, the meaning is clear. Nor is any natural language anything like 100% logical. But in writing that is anything more than casual, this “error” is to be avoided.

Yes, your example is (somewhat) ambiguous. I would lean to the child was she. Here, it's harder: As a child, I used to get ice cream from her. I would lean to child was I. I usually look for context in prior sentences to disambiguate/infer the meaning.
